# Hide custom attributes in front end

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, frontend, store-view

Magento newbie here.

I created custom attributes 'brand' and 'license' for my products, and they work just fine during product registration (I set them as dropdowns).  I'm also using a size attribute (also dropdown) plus Configurable and Simple products along with my attribute set for the various clothes I'm using in the products database.

On the store, the size attribute works just as intended, showing a selection dropdown on the frontend, but the issue is that there also are additional options for the brand and license requiring selection (put on the default 'choose an option'),

However, I don't want those to show themselves on the store (But I do want to keep them on the admin). Is there a way to hide them without altering the functioning? This is more of a practicality issue, since I can still add the products, provided I choose the brand/license, but the task seems meddlesome since I have only one option to choose from in both fields.

E.g.: I make a configurable product 'shirt A' and set the fields accordingly, then I create the associate products 'shirt A1' and 'shirt A2'to go with it. I make 'shirt A' available through search and catalog and the associates not individually available. I can access everything just fine in the final prodict, but I only want to see/set the size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just being dumb. It was just a matter of not checking the brand and license boxes when creating the configurable products.